# Dropdown list was hiding inside the modal popup window issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We are rendering **lightning:buttonMenu** and **Lightning:combobox**  within the modal. The actual issue was the dropDown List was hiding inside the modal.

Here we attached the screen shot for dropdown list was hiding inside the modal.

[image: btnMenuIssue inside the modal]

***We tried to fix this issue using the following CSS.***

```
.THIS .slds-modal__content{
    overflow: initial;
}
```

But If the modal content is high, the modal was cutoff in window view port.

See the attachment :
[image]

If anyone give solution for this, we are really appreciated.

Comment: why to change modal just change the menu to come above modal

Comment: @User6670 Initially, I tired to change the menu to come above the modal using the z-index: 9021 to a slds-dropdown__list class of lightning:buttonMenu. But is won't worked for me.

Comment: can you use scroll bar in that modal to see all menu items?

Comment: What we tried without scrolling we can able to see all the menu items inside the modal like as lightning:select.